# possible to add applicationIconBadgeNumbe to UIView?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, badge

could you please show me some example please?

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague.  You want to show the badge number inside of a UIView instance within your application?

Comment: i mean , Tabbar it have own Badge but UIView it doesn't how can i implement for UIView?